# Express middleware in a controller that is in a separate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this code that allows me to use `express-fileupload` middleware for uploading files:

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload({useTempFiles: true}));

app.post('/upload',   (req, res) => {
   const { image } = req.files;
   ...
}
```

It works, and the `image` in the `upload` endpoint is valid (is the image uploaded by the user in `<input type="file" name="image" />`).

However most of my routes are located in another file:

```
app.use('/api', routes);
```

**routes.js**:

```
router.get('/save', controller.save);
```

and in **controller.js**:

```
exports.save = (req, res) => {
    let {image} = req.files;
    ...
```

The `image` in the `save` endpoint would be `undefined`, because middleware is not applied.

However, if I try to apply it:

```
router.get('/save', fileUpload, controller.save);
```

the `save` endpoint is loading infinitely, the debugger never reaching the code inside the `save` method.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I get the file from inside the controller that's in another file?

Comment: Also, there's not going to be any fileupload with a `.get()` route.  Probably, you're only going to be doing file uploading with a POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not that the controller is in a separate file, the problem is the order in which you're defining the middleware and the routes. In Express, when you define a middleware using `app.use(middleware)`, it is only going to be applied to the routes that you define after that (which is way `app.post('/upload', ...)` is working).

So make sure your definitions are in the right order, in your case it will be:

```js
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload({ useTempFiles: true }));
app.use('/api', routes);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've solved it by moving the `fileUpload` to a `routes.js` file - applying it to a `router` there, but maybe your suggestion could have worked as well